# how to hex edit a .dll file

Tags: windows, dll, crystal-reports, hex

We've been using Seagate Info Desktop 7.5 for a while and it stopped working after 31 Dec 2010. After a lot searching on the web, we found out from the SAP threads that a particular dll file(ciweb.dll) had this line of code **"expires= Friday,31-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT"**,and this was causing the problem. The solution to the problem was to hexedit this dll file by changing the date to a later date. I have got no experience in hex editing a file. Would some please advise me with steps to do it?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a hex editor, and there are quite a few to choose from.

(I use Vim, but it has an initial learning curve, so you might find it easier to just [search for one](http://www.google.com/search?q=hex+editor))

It is not normally advised to edit DLLs in this way, since you can very easily break them, but reading the thread it seems the only viable workaround until a patch is released.

Just do need to be careful editing the DLL, in particular be careful not to add or remove any characters - just change the characters in the date (changing 2010 to 2020 should do it).  When you've finished editing, the file length should be exactly the same as when you started.  If it's not, you've screwed up and need to start again.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Hex Workshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/) 
It's a 30-day trial, and would suit your purposes perfectly.